# Spotify memory leak?

Tags: spotify

So, I'm using the undocumented JSON API.

I have a program that downloads this JSON object and deserializes it every 0.2 sec:

```
http://localhost:4300/remote/status.json&oauth=*Auth token*&csrf=*Cfid*
```

When my program runs, Spotify consumes more and more memory. I was wondering if anyone else using this API have had similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

Can't confirm it.

Using my Example-Application for the Local SpotifyAPI, memory-usage won't increase over time.
(I'm querying all 50ms)